# How to implement PRAGMA EXCEPTION_INIT in Postgres?

Tags: postgresql

How to implement PRAGMA EXCEPTION_INIT in Postgres.

.......................................................................................................

```
ELSIF l_errcode != 0

THEN

l_dyn_sql :='DECLARE myexc EXCEPTION; ' ||

'PRAGMA EXCEPTION_INIT (myexc, ' ||

TO_CHAR (l_errcode) ||');' ||

'BEGIN  RAISE myexc; END;';

EXECUTE IMMEDIATE l_dyn_sql;
END IF;
```

Comment: How to replace the same condition in postgres ? Please help me out ?

Comment: What does that code do? What are you trying to achieve with that?

Comment: we are creating a exception block in the SQL and using that dynamic sql in our function.

Answer (score 0):

There is no equivalent to Oracle's `PRAGMA EXCEPTION INIT` which is used initialize a user-defined exception.

[As documented in the manual](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/static/plpgsql-errors-and-messages.html#PLPGSQL-STATEMENTS-RAISE) you can raise an exception with a custom error message. You also don't need dynamic SQL to do that:

```
ELSIF l_errcode != 0 THEN
   raise exception 'Error with number % occurred', l_errocde;
END IF;
```

You can not specify your own error code though. The alternative syntax that accepts an error "name" or SQLSTATE, can only be used with the predefined exceptions [listed in the manual](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/static/errcodes-appendix.html)